# angular-spinner | Skipping $http.post error handling

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I am using [angular-spinner](https://github.com/urish/angular-spinner) to intercept all http request from my application and show a loading spinner.

Relevant code:-

```
//spinner configuration START
        myApp.factory('spinnerInterceptor', ['usSpinnerService', function(usSpinnerService) {
            return  {
                     request: function(config) {
                         usSpinnerService.spin('spinner-1');
                         return config;
                     },
                     response:function(config){
                         usSpinnerService.stop('spinner-1');
                         return config;
                     },
                     responseError:function(config){
                         usSpinnerService.stop('spinner-1');
                         return config;
                     }
            };
        }]);

        myApp.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
            $httpProvider.interceptors.push('spinnerInterceptor');
        }]);
        //spinner configuration END
```

Except starting/stopping the spinner , I am simply just returning the config object.

### Problem:-

One of my POST RESTful endpoint, return 404 status with an error message and still success handler of the $http block gets executed? Why?

```
$http({
                    method : 'POST',
                    url : url,
                    params :paramsJson,
                    data : _data
                }).success(function(data,status) {
                    // THIS GET EXECUTED AFTER SPINNER INTERCEPTOR  WITH STATUS 404 !!!!
                }).error(function(data,status) {
                    // THIS BLOCK I EXPECT TO RUN IN CASE OF 404 or any non 2XX response
                });
```

Before success/error handler of the $http, the spinnerInterceptor do get executed, which is somewhere playing with the error handling of the promise that gets returned.

When running my code without the spinner interceptor, everything works as expected.

Please help me fix this.

Comment: Found it. I was missing return $q.reject(rejection); in responseError

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is "responseError" interceptor. you need to reject request in this block. else error is already handled in you interceptor so what ever you return here will go to success block.

The corrected interceptor code is:

```
  responseError:function(config){//here we get response rename it
             usSpinnerService.stop('spinner-1');
             return $q.reject(config);
         }
```

You can refer to [Error Handling in angular](http://mysoftwareexperience.blogspot.in/2016/02/error-handling-and-authentication-with.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I had to develop an "automatic" spinner recently in a project. I used $q promises to signal success / error on the interceptor methods and it worked fine. My code was:

(function () {
    'use strict';

```
function httpBusyInterceptor($q) {


    function _responseError (response) {                      
        //Hide spinner code
        return $q.reject(response);
    }

    function _response (response) {                    
        //Hide spinner code
        return response || $q.when(response);
    }

    function _request (config) {                       
        //Show spinner code
        return config || $q.when(config);
    }

   return {
        request: _request,
        response: _response,
        responseError: _responseError
    };
}
httpBusyInterceptor.$inject = ['$q'];

angular.module('common.ui').factory('httpBusyInterceptor', httpBusyInterceptor);
```

})();